# MySQL replaces my PHP input data

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, replace, passwords

So, I've been trying to create a Signup/Login process using PHP and MySQL. I created a Signup form, and a handling page. Then I tred it out, set the email as `a@a.com` and password as `MyPassword`.

I then checked the database and got surprised. The email was correctly inputted, alright, but the password wasn't! It was one of the passwords that I used to test before, and it is a pretty personal one.

Every time I tried it again, the same thing happened. The password was always changed to my personal one whenever I signed up.

The problem is that, in my code, I don't have that personal password, anywhere. I only used it to test my signup flow once, and now it's stuck to my database!

Here, I registered using test credentials. The password is `asd` and it's obviously 3 letters long.
[image]

But when I check the database, I see the following. Even though I edited the password so you can't see it, it's still obvious it's more than 3 letters long.
[image]

Is this some kind of MySQL over-writing thing, that I just don't know about yet?

Here is the full code of the SignUp Page (Might be a little long, bear with me):

```
<?php
session_start();
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['signUpemail'];
$password = $_POST['signUppassword'];
include("mysql_base.php");
echo "Preparing MYSQL Statement...<br>";
echo "<script>";
echo "firstPart()";
echo "function firstPart() {";
echo "document.write('Starting to process MYSQL Statement...')";
echo "window.setTimeout(secondPart(),2000)";
echo "}";
echo "function secondPart() {";
echo "document.write('Starting to stop processing MSYQL Statement...')";
echo "}";
echo "</script>";
echo "Started to proccess...<br>";
$sql = "INSERT INTO pages_accounts (email, pass, firstname, lastname, confirm) VALUES ('".$email."','".$password."','".$firstName."','".$lastName."','0')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === true){
  echo "<b>SIGNUP SUCCESS</b><br>";
  echo "SUCH HAPPINESS. WOW. MMM.<br><br>";
  echo "--Check your mail for a confirmation email. Check SPAM too!--";
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'From: FoxInFlame Pages<pages@foxinflame.tk>' . "\r\n";
  $message = "
  <html>
  <body>
  <center>
  <div style='background-color:orange'><h1>Confirm your Account</h1><br><h3>At FoxInFlame Pages</h3></div>
  You seem to have registered for an account at FoxInFlame Pages. Now please click on the following link to complete your registration, and start creating amazing websites!<br><a href='http://www.foxinflame.tk/pages/confirm.php?id=".$conn->insert_id."'>Click Here</a>
  </center>
  </body>
  </html>
  ";
  mail($email, "[CONFIRM] Account on FoxInFlame Pages", $message);
} else {
  echo "MUCH SADNESS. SUCH DEPRESSION. FAIL ERROR. NO RETURN.";
  echo "Error: ".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
};
?>
```

Comment: Did the password get saved into your browser form field history?  Can you post some code?

Comment: Seeing the login/signup page isn't as important as seeing the code. My guess is that there's SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: **DO NOT VISIT THE LINK** - this is just spam

Comment: @samlev  did you flag this?

Comment: @samlev Here. I deleted the link, added pictures. Fair? Now can you answer the question.

Comment: @DavidSoussan yes I did.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also you should be [Hashing your passwords](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Comment: @samlev I heard about it already. I know, I know. Like adding `value) DROP TABLE things` right? Before that, I'm just wondering about the whole password getting changed thing. Hashing passwords? I'll check it out.

Comment: show me your `INSERT` statement please!

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO pages_accounts (email, pass, firstname, lastname, confirm) VALUES ('".$email."','".$password."','".$firstName."','".$lastName."','0')";`

Comment: Yeah, the ability to drop tables. It also exposes some of your table schema when you deliberately cause errors. For example: [setting the first name to `'` shows me the table structure, and your password](http://i.imgur.com/K7U4EDX.png)

Comment: ok... post full fragment of code where all variables came from. and how you execute this query against mysql

Comment: Can you edit the question and show us how you create the $password variable from $_POST?

Comment: Short story - he isn't. I'm not sure what his code looks like internally, but `$password` is being set independently from what is being posted.

Comment: So, I can escape the strings. Wouldn't it have the same trouble/problem?

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will be in `include("mysql_base.php");`. That file will be setting `$password` for it's own internal use, which is overwriting the `$password` variable that you get from `$_POST`;

2 options to get around this:

**1** - Open the database connection first.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("mysql_base.php");

$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['signUpemail'];
$password = $_POST['signUppassword'];
```

**2** - Use different variable names:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("mysql_base.php");

$signup_firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$signup_lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$signup_email = $_POST['signUpemail'];
$signup_password = $_POST['signUppassword'];
```

Aside from this, the password field on the sign up page doesn't have `name="signUppassword"`, and you have no SQL Injection protection.

Comment: mmm. I will check it.

Comment: Ah. Worked. Like a charm. Thank you samlev. I even forgive you for calling me spam. (Well maybe not, but whatever). I named the variabled in mysql_base.php to `mysql_password`, `mysql_username`... So on... From now on, I need to be careful of naming variables...

Answer (score 0):

On your page I see:

```
  <input style="color:white" type="password" name="password" required="" autocomplete="off">
```

So your input name is **password**

But in your code you are trying to get **signUppassword**:

```
  $password = $_POST['signUppassword'];
```

Do you have some transformation somewhere ? javascript?

Comment: You are looking at the login part. It might be confusing. I'm talking about the SignUp process, where the password gets transformed. I am sure that the input has a name of signUpname, and signUppassword.

Comment: No  I am looking on **sign up** form http://www.foxinflame.tk/pages/loginSignup.php  By the way **both** forms use **<input name="password"**

Comment: Alright. Does that, well, affect my flow of the signup proccess?

Comment: Sorry, but I fixed the name to signUppassword, and it didn't work. I tried samlev's and it did, so well, sorry.